# extract private youtube playlist video links

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to extract the video link of my private playlist. but i am unable to do

I used the below code to get the list

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
$cont = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/'.$_POST['a'].'/?v=2')); ?>
<?php $feed = $cont->feed->entry; ?>
<?php if(count($feed)): foreach($feed as $item): // youtube start ?>
<?php echo $item->{'media$group'}->{'yt$videoid'}->{'$t'} ?>
    <?php echo $item->title->{'$t'}  ?>


<?php endforeach; endif;  }?>
```

but this doesn't work. i need to extract only link with video title.

i have my account details with me how its possible using php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want a private playlist, this will need to be an authenticated call, so you'll first have to set up an oAuth exchange. In PHP the easiest way to do this is with the gapi client; you can see more info (and get the library and sample code) here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#retrieve_my_uploads

It will require you to use the client ID and secret for your registered app, though (don't forget to turn on the YouTube API v3 in the registered app!).

Once the oAuth is working, you can change the sample code listed above to very easily get your private playlist; starting with line 40, you'll have to use a call that's something like this:

```
$playlistResponse = $youtube->playlist->listPlaylists('contentDetails', array(
      'id' => $_POST['a'], // assuming this variable represents the id of your playlist
));
```

You'll also have to somewhat modify the code after that block to be able to parse the playlist feed and get your info.

Comment: Sir, i am working from my local pc so is there any other way without using OAuth

Comment: The only other option is to use the old clientLogin method (https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_clientlogin), but that isn't much easier ... you still have to exchange tokens and then have your server-side app set the authentication headers; clientLogin has been deprecated for nearly 2 years now and so isn't a long term solution.